# React partial rerender tree

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So I have an `appbar` and a `drawer`. Like this:

```
export default function AppRouter() {
  //Drawer mobile toggle function
  const [drawerMobileOpen, setDrawerMobileOpen] = useState(false);
  const handleDrawerToggle = function() {
    setDrawerMobileOpen(!drawerMobileOpen);
  };

  return (
    <Router>
      <Authentication loginPage={<Login />}>
        <StyledResponsiveDrawerWrapper>
          <Drawer open={drawerMobileOpen} drawerToggle={handleDrawerToggle}>
            <DrawerContent />
          </Drawer>
          <StyledContent>
            <AppBar position="fixed" drawerToggle={handleDrawerToggle} />
            <StyledMain>
              <Switch>
                <Route path="/dashboard/" component={suspensePage(Dashboard)} />
                <Route path="/administrator/" component={suspensePage(Administrator)} />
              </Switch>
            </StyledMain>
          </StyledContent>
        </StyledResponsiveDrawerWrapper>
      </Authentication>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

In the `routes` I have my pages. Now what happens is, if I click the menu button on the `appBar` the `useState` is updated (`handleDrawerToggle`) and sets the `drawerMobileOpen` to `true` or `false`.

That works perfectly. But because the state in this Component changes, a rerender happens. The rerender will load the current page in the route again. This page has an api call, so every time I toggle the drawer, an apicall is made.

How can I prevent that the page is rerendered when the state of the drawer changes. The drawer should rerender ofcourse. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probelm is that you are using an HOC inside the render method which creates a new instance of the component eveytime. You should instead create component instances from HOC outside of the functional component

```
const SuspenseDashboard = suspensePage(Dashboard)
const SuspenseAdministrator = suspensePage(Administrator)
export default function AppRouter() {
  //Drawer mobile toggle function
  const [drawerMobileOpen, setDrawerMobileOpen] = useState(false);
  const handleDrawerToggle = function() {
    setDrawerMobileOpen(!drawerMobileOpen);
  };

  return (
    <Router>
      <Authentication loginPage={<Login />}>
        <StyledResponsiveDrawerWrapper>
          <Drawer open={drawerMobileOpen} drawerToggle={handleDrawerToggle}>
            <DrawerContent />
          </Drawer>
          <StyledContent>
            <AppBar position="fixed" drawerToggle={handleDrawerToggle} />
            <StyledMain>
              <Switch>
                <Route path="/dashboard/" component={SuspenseDashboard} />
                <Route path="/administrator/" component={SuspenseAdministrator} />
              </Switch>
            </StyledMain>
          </StyledContent>
        </StyledResponsiveDrawerWrapper>
      </Authentication>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So simple... I understand why this happens. Appreciatie it.